# How to make filtered emails obey my filter rule when selecting 'Not Spam' option in spam folder?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I have a forwarded email sending email to my Gmail address, I then filter those emails using these settings:

`Matches: to:(@myemail.com)
Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "My Label"`

Works great, but there is an issue when an email to that address goes into spam.

If I choose **Not Spam** the email gets put into the **Inbox** folder so it doesn't respect my **skip the inbox** rule. It does get the label I want but skips the inbox.

Is there a way to make it respect my rule?

Comment: I guess this is not doable because spam folder is kinda sub-layer (sandbox) of Inbox so "Not Spam" will always send it into Inbox (parent layer)